# Adding a button to the bottom of every view - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button

I'm working on an iOS application. I would like to add a constant button that will show at the bottom of every view within the app. I could obviously just create the button on every view. However, I'm sure there will be a way of creating the button once and having it appear multiple times.

Does anyone have any tips on how this can be done?

I effectively want a navigation bar on the bottom of my app that has a custom button on it?

Comment: Did you check out `UITabBarController`?

Comment: Add button on main window and bring that to front

Comment: By main window do you mean my View that follows the navigation controller?

Comment: @benjiiiii Check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Any of view in main window of app. so it will be visible in every screen

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.addSubview(yourButton)
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.bringSubview(toFront: yourButton)
```

Hope it is helpful